# UITableView reload data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i'm making a navigation based application for iphone.

one of my view controllers looks like this:

```
@interface NewComputerViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

so i'm using a `UITableView` to show data.

when the view loads, I use a button in the top navigation bar to run a function `loadStuff` load some stuff in a Dictionary.

My question: how do I repopulate the table view in that viewcontroller from that `loadStuff` function (which belongs to the view controller)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can always use `[tableView reloadData]` method!

But if you have some data stored locally and loading new stuff from some server then you can go for:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

And if you want to delete existing row you can use

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: whats will be arrayofindex paths i am using mutabledictionary for table data and i want to delete one object from dictionary and update tableview

Answer (score 27):

Try using `[tableView reloadData];` (where tableView is the name of your instance variable)

Comment: @Emil: I just hope nobody tries it someday. ;)

Comment: Nothing will happen on most machines though, nearly every OS have a block now.. A shame, though :P

Comment: @sudorm-rf and &Emil: I've just tried it on my Mac. It does nothing. (Why? Because there's no file name or anything that could be expanded by file name expansion. And because `-f` is used, no error message is displayed and the command simply ends with zero return code.)

Comment: some men just want to watch the world burn ;P

Comment: @sudorm-rf Hi, I am new to Linux. Please may you explain what you're username linux terminal command does and why its funny?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff, this may help you: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2759359?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 6):

When even reloading...

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

will not reload the edited rows/cell, maybe the IBOutlet of tableView is not connected in XIB file?

This could be one of the reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Very important is the fact, that you need to make sure, that the source of your tableview reflects your changes too.

When you i.e. remove something, [tableView reloadData] won't do anything when you do not delete the item in your source first.

I had this issue in following situation:
I had a tableview which showed some files in my document folder. Then I wanted to delete some files and I deleted them in the documents-folder, but they still appear in my list. I tried [tableView reloadData] and all other suggested answers in this post, but there were still the files listed.
When I closed the tableview and opened it again, then the list was fine. Why?
Well, because I filled an NSArray with all my files -> this is my "source" for the tableView. So when I delete a file, I do not only need to delete the file in the documents-folder, I need to remove it from the array too. -> So I made an NSMutableArray to have the ability to remove it.
Then call [tableView reloadData] and the list is fine. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are setting `datasource` and delegate for `tableView`.

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Make sure the proper delegate and datasource method is implemented in the controller.

In the loadStuff method, call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

In swift, the same:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 3):

at the end of your function **loadstuff** reload the contents of ur table by writing the following code:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[tableView reloadData];` where tableview is the name of your UITableView