# table view data update in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in my iphone app  i am adding data to table view on click of button but its not getting updated.It ll update only if i reopen the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [tableview reloadData]

in wiewWillApear method

Answer (score 5):

Use `[yourTableView reloadData]` to tell the tableview to reload its data and be updated.

Comment: How would that work with table views created in Interface Builder (sorry I'm a beginner)? I've the problem that the row number doesn't update when a row of the table is deleted. Thanks!

Comment: IB or by code, same story. A `UITableView` created by instanciating a NIB (and with an IBOutlet variable or property pointing to the instanciated tableview) is just like an `UITableView` created by code, no difference here. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! There's no problem. I just try to understand. The hint with the IBOutlet is good though.

Comment: Actually, an ivar or `@property` annotated with `IBOutlet` is no different from any other ivar or `@property`. The `IBOutlet` keyword (actually `#defined` to nothing) is just here to let IB know you want to expose this ivar/property in your XIB to be able to connect some object to it, so that when IB instanciates the object, it can affect it to this ivar/property, the same way you would have done it by code. Writing `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:...];` is quite the same as creating the tableview via IB and connect it to the `tableView` IBOutlet property in your XIB.

Comment: Thanks for the real good details. I'll try to get that implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `[tableView reloadData]` method on button click after updating the table view's data source.

So something like this:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Update data source of table first
    [tableView reloadData]
}
```

Also check this out: [UITableView reload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094972/uitableview-reload-data)

Answer (score 1):

Preview Controller to reload its data from its data source.

```
- (void) reloadData
```

The display is recomputed only if the current preview item has changed.