# Reload data in UITableView after plist has been updated?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist, reload, property-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableView reload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094972/uitableview-reload-data)

I have a UITableView in my app with the data stored in a property list (plist). The plist can be updated/re-downloaded from the internet and the plist is replaced. How can I reload the table view data without having to reload the view? I want the data to update when I call a method.

Comment: Use the UITableView's reloadData method?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I don't see why you can't simply call the `reloadData` method on the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Already tried that, I am trying to call it from the app delegate while the table view is in another view controller. - @middaparka

Comment: Where are you re-(reading) the plist? (You should really update your question to provide sufficient information, otherwise this is liable to be a somewhat painful guessing game.) :-)

Comment: In the app delegate while the table view is in a UIViewController.

Comment: To be honest, I'd be very tempted to update your question to provide a bigger picture overview of what you've done and what you're attempting to do. The correct solution will be to call the reloadData method on the UITableView (perhaps by making the UIViewController in question a delegate of the class responsible for the reload), but it sounds like there might be a bigger architectural issue at the heart of your problem.

Comment: Sure, if you want to update my question go ahead, I don't mind :)