# Reload UITableView properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem here. My app saves some objects into a SQLite database and that database is the source for my UITableView. Everything works fine, except if a add a new object to my database at runtime, my UITableView doesn´t update its content. Here´s my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self daten];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(NSMutableArray *) daten{

if (daten)
    return daten;

    self.daten = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }


    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM  Daten";
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            .......
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return daten;
}
}
```

I think the problem is here:

```
if (daten)
    return daten;

    self.daten = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

But if my database gets a new object at runtime, my array is not nil at that moment and will be just returned without the new object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just add :-

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: replace edited code with [self.daten removeAllObjects]; and then reload data from your database

Answer (score 0):

You can call reloadData on the table view.

This question seems to be a duplicate of: [UITableView reload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094972/uitableview-reload-data).

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling: [[tableView reloadData]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW19)

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a method called reloadData that reloads the rows and sections of a table.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your process for inserting a new record but that is where you will need to address the data for reload. If you do not set daten to nil or insert the info into the array at that point, your call to reload will receive the same data, showing nothing new.

daten is mutable so you can insert the new info using

```
[self.daten insertObject:myInfo atIndex:myIndex];
```

The procedure, after successful insertion of a record into db:

```
* insert related info into your NSMutableArray.
* insert row into tableview or reload tableview.
```

Alternatively, you can set daten to nil and let it refill from the original method.

```
self.daten = nil;
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Assuming your tableview datasource methods are returning values based on [self daten], the next call will repopulate the array. In this case, there would be no reason to make it mutable though.

Additionally, there is no reason to call [self daten] in viewDidLoad. When your datasource method asks for the array, it will be created and filled as per your accessor.