# Adding from text & date to a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a **`UIViewController`** that contains a text field, date field and a button. In addition I have a **`UITableViewController`** that has a `Mutablearray`. How can I pass the values from my text field and date field to create a new item in the `Mutablearray` in the other class?

**Edit:**
My **`UIViewController`** where the the text and date fields are is empty (Kinda need help here). and my **`UITableViewController`** is below:

```
@interface TableView ()
@end

@implementation TableView
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];



}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return items.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TodoItemRow"];
   cell.textLabel.text= [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

   }


   @end
```

Comment: duplicate.check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I did @ismail  thank you

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094972/uitableview-reload-data